# how get value of textview (with currentview ) with viewpager?

Tags: android, textview, android-viewpager

**how get value of textview (with currentview ) in viewpager?**

**Problem** 
*i gettext of textview but now current showing textview its gee=ttingtext of next view's textview*

**class Test**

```
package "name";

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by name on 26-Mar-16.
 */
public class Test extends Activity {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;


    private List<String> testContactName = new ArrayList<>();
    public MyAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);


        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.testvp);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(50);

        getAllContacts();

    }

    public void getAllContacts() {
        DatabaseHelper dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();

        String query = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME;

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for (int c = 0; c < cursor.getCount(); c++) {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content"));
                cursor.moveToNext();
               /* String count= String.valueOf(cursor.getCount());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), count , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                testContactName.add(name);

                //  testContactName.notifyAll();

                Log.i("Name: " + "" + "---", name);

            }mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    private class MyAdapter  extends PagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return testContactName.size();

        }
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View collection, Object object) {

            return object == collection;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test1, null);


           TextView pagenumber;
            pagenumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_test1);

            try {
                pagenumber.setText(testContactName.get(position));

           **method i called like**



 imgcopy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setClipboard(mViewPager.getFocusedChild(), pagenumber.getText().toString());

            }
        });




            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            ( collection).addView(view);
            return view;

        }



        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
            ( collection).removeView((View) view);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }


}
```

**method i use to copytoclipborad**

```
private void setClipboard(View context,String text) {
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(text);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", text);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Copied To ClipBoard",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**test.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/testvp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**test1.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/tv_test1"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: From where are you calling - imgcopy.setOnClickListener() ?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari dear i updated ans ..see and tell what i m doing wrong ..  and i don't get that i just simply gettext of textview (named pagenumber)but y it isn't setting the current shown textview value...

Comment: @ShadabAnsari can u ans?